# Retreive date from rolling maximum

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, window-functions, over-clause

I have a SQL Server table with a date (`session_date`) and a value (`price`).

| session_date | price |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-12-31 | 10 |
| 2022-12-30 | 9 |
| 2022-12-29 | 5 |
| 2022-12-28 | 7 |
| 2022-12-27 | 2 |
| 2022-12-26 | 9 |
| 2022-12-25 | 3 |
| 2022-12-24 | 1 |

I want to compute the rolling maximum over the last 3 rows (dates) and retrieve the session_date associated with each maximum:

| session_date | price | rolling_max | rolling_last_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-12-31 | 4 | 9 | 2022-12-29 |
| 2022-12-30 | 4 | 9 | 2022-12-29 |
| 2022-12-29 | 9 | 9 | 2022-12-29 |
| 2022-12-28 | 7 | 7 | 2022-12-28 |
| 2022-12-27 | 2 | 4 | 2022-12-26 |
| 2022-12-26 | 4 | 4 | 2022-12-26 |
| 2022-12-25 | 3 | 3 | 2022-12-25 |
| 2022-12-24 | 1 | 1 | 2022-12-24 |

I'm using this query to compute the rolling maximum, but how can I get the associated `session_date` ?

```
select session_date
, price
, max(price) over (order by session_date rows between 3 preceding and current row) as rolling_max
from my_table
```

Comment: You want the value of `session_date` which has the max `price` within the window, is that the logic?

Comment: Yes it's the logic @Charlieface

Answer (score 3):

Here is one method that avoids self-joins and complex `LEAD/LAG` expressions.
It would work with simple data types like `int`, `date`, `decimal`. With `float` you need to be careful to not lose precision when converting to/from the text. I would argue that price should never be stored as `float`, I prefer `money` type to store this kind of data.

**Idea:**
Combine values of two columns into a single column that can be used in a rolling `MAX` function and then split them back.

Here I combine them into an ordinary text `varchar`. If you use `int` and `date` you can combine into `varbinary`, which may be a bit more efficient.

```
REPLACE(STR(price, 20, 0), ' ', '0') + CONVERT(varchar(10), session_date, 126) AS combined
```

Convert `price` into a string, make sure you make it left-padded with zeros, so that it is sorted properly.
Convert `session_date` into a string and attach it to the `price`.
Later split this string back into corresponding values.

**Sample data**

```
DECLARE @my_table TABLE (
    session_date date,
    price decimal(15,2)
);

insert into @my_table values
('2022-12-31',  4),
('2022-12-30',  4),
('2022-12-29',  9),
('2022-12-28',  7),
('2022-12-27',  2),
('2022-12-26',  4),
('2022-12-25',  3),
('2022-12-24',  1);
```

**Query**

```
WITH
CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
        *
        ,max(combined) over (order by session_date DESC ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND 3 FOLLOWING) as rolling_combined
    FROM
        @my_table AS T
        CROSS APPLY
        (
            SELECT
                REPLACE(STR(price, 20, 0), ' ', '0') + CONVERT(varchar(10), session_date, 126) AS combined
        ) AS A
)
SELECT
    session_date
    ,price
    ,CAST(LEFT(rolling_combined, 20) AS decimal(15,2)) AS rolling_price
    ,CAST(RIGHT(rolling_combined, 10) as date) AS rolling_date
    ,rolling_combined
FROM CTE
ORDER BY session_date DESC;
```

It is important to have the same `ORDER BY` in the main query and in the `MAX` to avoid second sort.

**Result**

I included the combined column in the output to show how it looks like.

```
+--------------+-------+---------------+--------------+--------------------------------+
| session_date | price | rolling_price | rolling_date |        rolling_combined        |
+--------------+-------+---------------+--------------+--------------------------------+
| 2022-12-31   | 4.00  | 9.00          | 2022-12-29   | 000000000000000000092022-12-29 |
| 2022-12-30   | 4.00  | 9.00          | 2022-12-29   | 000000000000000000092022-12-29 |
| 2022-12-29   | 9.00  | 9.00          | 2022-12-29   | 000000000000000000092022-12-29 |
| 2022-12-28   | 7.00  | 7.00          | 2022-12-28   | 000000000000000000072022-12-28 |
| 2022-12-27   | 2.00  | 4.00          | 2022-12-26   | 000000000000000000042022-12-26 |
| 2022-12-26   | 4.00  | 4.00          | 2022-12-26   | 000000000000000000042022-12-26 |
| 2022-12-25   | 3.00  | 3.00          | 2022-12-25   | 000000000000000000032022-12-25 |
| 2022-12-24   | 1.00  | 1.00          | 2022-12-24   | 000000000000000000012022-12-24 |
+--------------+-------+---------------+--------------+--------------------------------+
```

Comment: Great answer. "It is important to have the same ORDER BY in the main query and in the MAX to avoid second sort." in other words: if you want to sort by `session_date ASC` then you need to change to `max(combined) over (order by session_date ASC ROWS 3 PRECEDING) as rolling_combined`

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
with cte as (
  select session_date
  , price
  , max(price) over (order by session_date rows between 3 preceding and current row) as rolling_max  from my_table
)
select c.*, t.session_date as rolling_last_date
from cte c
inner join (
  select price, min(session_date) as session_date
  from my_table t
  group by price
) t on t.price = c.rolling_max 
order by session_date desc
```

To get `rolling_last_date` you will have to join your result with the list the smallest `session_date` by price using `GROUP BY` and `MIN()`

Result :

```
session_date    price   rolling_max rolling_last_date
2022-12-31      4       9           2022-12-29
2022-12-30      4       9           2022-12-29
2022-12-29      9       9           2022-12-29
2022-12-28      7       7           2022-12-28
2022-12-27      2       4           2022-12-26
2022-12-26      4       4           2022-12-26
2022-12-25      3       3           2022-12-25
2022-12-24      1       1           2022-12-24
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/ug2AyLTl)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without any joins, purely by using window functions. You need to use a pile of `LAG` or `LEAD` functions to pick the date matching the highest price of the window.

You must do this with a derived table, as you first need to calculate the max price and the individual `LAG` or `LEAD` values.

```sql
SELECT
  session_date,
  price,
  maxPrice,
  dateOfMaxPrice =
    CASE maxPrice
    WHEN lagP1 THEN lagS1
    WHEN lagP2 THEN lagS2
    WHEN lagP3 THEN lagS3
    ELSE session_date
    END
FROM (
    SELECT *,
      maxPrice = MAX(price) OVER (ORDER BY session_date DESC ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND 3 FOLLOWING),
      lagP1 = LEAD(price, 1) OVER (ORDER BY session_date DESC),
      lagP2 = LEAD(price, 2) OVER (ORDER BY session_date DESC),
      lagP3 = LEAD(price, 3) OVER (ORDER BY session_date DESC),
      lagS1 = LEAD(session_date, 1) OVER (ORDER BY session_date DESC),
      lagS2 = LEAD(session_date, 2) OVER (ORDER BY session_date DESC),
      lagS3 = LEAD(session_date, 3) OVER (ORDER BY session_date DESC)
    FROM my_table t
) t
ORDER BY
  session_date DESC;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/Z6DF6-sU)

Note that I have used `LEAD` with a descending sort, rather than `LAG` ascending, to match your outer `ORDER BY`, this means the server does not have to resort the rows after doing the calculations. The result is the same.

Comment: Seems promising, but in this situation it returns some NULL : [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/jqZ0arHF), do you have an idea ?

Comment: I struggle to understand why your first answer is not working with float / decimal and returns null . If I want to increase the windows size, for example to 100, it will not be convinent.

Comment: Because `maxPrice` is being calculated *per row*, so when you do another `MAX(CASE` it only calculates it for that row. Do a `SELECT *` and you will se what is going on. If the window is large it's probably better to just use a self-join like the other answer.

Comment: @Charlieface, I think it is possible to avoid both self-joins and complex `LEAD/LAG` expressions. I added an answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use your query within a CTE then use subquery to to add max session_date when price is the maxRollingPrice and session_date is within the same range.

```
create table my_table (
  session_date  date,
  price int
);

insert into my_table values
('2022-12-31',  4),
('2022-12-30',  4),
('2022-12-29',  9),
('2022-12-28',  7),
('2022-12-27',  2),
('2022-12-26',  4),
('2022-12-25',  3),
('2022-12-24',  1);
```

Query:

```
with maxRollingPrice as(
select session_date
, price
, max(price) over (order by session_date rows between 3 preceding and current row) as rolling_max 
  
from my_table)
select *,
  (select  max(session_date) from my_table  mt where datediff(day,mt.session_date,rp.session_date) between 0 and 3 and mt.price=rolling_max) rolling_last_date
from maxRollingPrice rp  
order by rp.session_date desc
```

Output:

| session_date | price | rolling_max | rolling_last_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-12-31 | 4 | 9 | 2022-12-29 |
| 2022-12-30 | 4 | 9 | 2022-12-29 |
| 2022-12-29 | 9 | 9 | 2022-12-29 |
| 2022-12-28 | 7 | 7 | 2022-12-28 |
| 2022-12-27 | 2 | 4 | 2022-12-26 |
| 2022-12-26 | 4 | 4 | 2022-12-26 |
| 2022-12-25 | 3 | 3 | 2022-12-25 |
| 2022-12-24 | 1 | 1 | 2022-12-24 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/1uoYm4q4)